# WARNING: A response with a 200 (Ok) status should have an entity. Make sure that resource returns one or sets the status to 204

Tags: java, servlets

In the context of a Servlet container what does this mean:

```
WARNING: A response with a 200 (Ok) status should have an entity. Make sure that resource "http://localhost:8080/parse/custom/usermanagement/hello_method" returns one or sets the status to 204 (No content).
```

Where I can clearly see from the client (I am using Postman) that the response is there (e.g. `{"hello":"body"}`)

Comment: Is the body also there (displayed in plain text) when you call http://localhost:8080/parse/custom/usermanagement/hello_method with your browser?

Comment: Yes the text is displayed

Comment: Hmm, my only idea would be that you form the response first and then apply the entity in another stage... but it's nothing more than an idea.
Let me know when you fixed it!

Comment: Its been a few years since question was posted, did you happen to get a fix for this?